# React component CSS file

Tags: css, reactjs

React component CSS file CSS code does not work. Component file CSS has been imported।

```
import React from 'react';
import { Carousel } from 'react-bootstrap';
import './Banner';
```

Comment: check the console errors and try to use import './Banner.css', may be you have to configure your webpack css loaders;

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `import './Banner';` use this `import './Banner.css';`.
Or
In General,
use `import './styleFileName.css';`
to import any CSS file.